# BASH scripting - unable to split string from grepped output and pass it one by one to a variable

Tags: string, bash, shell, grep

I'm a beginner to bash scripting and been writing a script to check different log files and I'm bit stuck here.

```
clientlist=/path/to/logfile/which/consists/of/client/names 
#i will grep only the client name from the file which has multiple log lines 
clients=$(grep --color -i 'list of client assets:' $clientlist | cut -d":" -f1 )
echo "Clients : $clients"
#For example "Clients: Apple
#                      Samsung
#                      Nokia"
#number of clients may vary from time to time
assets=("$clients".log)
echo assets: "$assets"
```

The code above greps the client name from the log file and i'm trying to use the grepped client name (each) to construct a logfile with each client name.

The number of clients is indefinite and may vary from time to time.

The code I have returns the client name as a whole

```
assets: Apple
        Samsung
        Nokia.log
```

and I'm bit unsure of how to cut the string and pass it on one by one to return the assets which has `.log` for each client name. How can i do this ?

```
Apple.log
Samsung.log
Nokia.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Apologies if I have misunderstood the task)

**Using `awk`**

if your input file (I'll call it `clients.txt`) is:

```
Clients: Apple
         Samsung
         Nokia
```

The following `awk` step:

```
awk '{print $NF".log"}' clients.txt
```

outputs:

```
Apple.log
Samsung.log
Nokia.log
```

(You can pipe straight into awk and omit the file name if the pipe stream is as the file contents in the above example).

It is highly likely that a simple `awk` procedure can perform the entire task beginning with the 'clientlist' you process with `grep` (`awk` has all the functionality of `grep` built-in) but I'd need to know the structure of the origial file to extract the client names.

Comment: Excellent! This actually worked for me. I had to omit the file name and pipe straight into awk and it worked. Thankyou so much.

Answer (score 1):

One `awk` idea:

```
assets=( $(awk -F: '/list of client assets:/ {print $2".log"}' "${clientlist}") )

# or

mapfile -t assets < <(awk -F: '/list of client assets:/ {print $2".log"}' "${clientlist}")
```

Where:

- `-F:` - define input field delimiter as `:`
- `/list of client assets:/` - for lines that contain the string `list of clients assets:` print the 2nd `:`-delimited field and append the string `.log` on the end

One `sed` idea:

```
assets=( $(sed 's/.*://; s/$/.log/' "${clientlist}") )

# or

mapfile -t assets < <(sed 's/.*://; s/$/.log/' "${clientlist}")
```

Where:

- `s/.*://` - strip off everything up to the `:`
- `s/$/.log/` - replace end of line with `.log`

Both generate:

```
$ typeset -p assets
declare -a assets=([0]="Apple.log" [1]="Samsung.log" [2]="Nokia.log")

$ echo "${assets[@]}"
Apple.log Samsung.log Nokia.log

$ printf "%s\n" "${assets[@]}"
Apple.log
Samsung.log
Nokia.log

$ for i in "${!assets[@]}"; do echo "assets[$i] = ${assets[$indx]}"; done
assets[0] = Apple.log
assets[1] = Samsung.log
assets[2] = Nokia.log
```

**NOTE:** the alternative answers using `mapfile` address the issue referenced in Charles Duffy comment (see [bash pitfall #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_.2BICY.29_.29)); `readarray` is a synonym for `mapfile`

Comment: [BashPitfalls #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_.2BICY.29_.29) applies. Better to suggest `readarray -t assets < <(...)` than `assets=( $(...) )` for populating an array from line-oriented input.